# PHPUnit: How to mock an internally called function by the method under test

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

In the below example, I want to mock the calling of `getBaseValue()` inside the `multipliedValue()`. But I cannot figure it out.

```
class Sample
{
    function multipliedValue()
    {
      $value = $this->getBaseValue();
      return $value * 2;
    }

    function getBaseValue()
    {
      return 2;
    }
}
```

I have used PHPUnit mocking, but it didn't work. So, I used the following code:

```
class SampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  function testMultipliedValueIfBaseValueIsFalse()
  {
        $mockedObject = $this->getMockBuilder(Sample::class)
            ->setMethods(['multipliedValue', 'getBaseValue'])
            ->getMock();
        $mockedObject->expects($this->any())
            ->method("getBaseValue")
            ->willReturn(false);
        $result = $mockedObject->multipliedValue();
        $this->assertFalse($result);
  }
}
```

I tried to create a global function, but only force one of the method to return my desired value, the rest just go as they are. How should I approach this test?

The error I am currently getting is for the `$this` in the `multipliedValue()` method, which treats it as the stubbed object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the methods listed in the `->setMethods()` will be stubbed and return `null` by default so if you only want to stub `getBaseValue` then do:

```
$mockedObject = $this->getMockBuilder(Sample::class)
        ->setMethods(['getBaseValue'])
        ->getMock();
    $mockedObject->expects($this->any())
        ->method("getBaseValue")
        ->willReturn(false);
    $result = $mockedObject->multipliedValue();
    $this->assertFalse($result);
```

Comment: Doing this would result in error  `undefined method SampleTest::getBaseValue()` Because `getBaseValue()` is internally called by the `multipliedValue()` function.

Comment: No you're right. I had a mistake in doing this. Thanks very much